# Multilingual slideshow

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7, multilingual

I have this code for a slideshow in my `Drupal 7`, `Nexus 7.x-1.3 theme`.

My website is multilingual and I need to use a different image for every language, eg. I would like to change `slide-image-1.jpg` (`en` language) with other image-name for (`gr` language).

My code:

```
 <?php if ($is_front): ?>
    <?php if (theme_get_setting('slideshow_display','nexus')): ?>
      <?php 
    $slide1_head = check_plain(theme_get_setting('slide1_head','nexus'));   $slide1_desc = check_markup(theme_get_setting('slide1_desc','nexus'), 'full_html'); $slide1_url = check_plain(theme_get_setting('slide1_url','nexus'));
    $slide2_head = check_plain(theme_get_setting('slide2_head','nexus'));   $slide2_desc = check_markup(theme_get_setting('slide2_desc','nexus'), 'full_html'); $slide2_url = check_plain(theme_get_setting('slide2_url','nexus'));
    $slide3_head = check_plain(theme_get_setting('slide3_head','nexus'));   $slide3_desc = check_markup(theme_get_setting('slide3_desc','nexus'), 'full_html'); $slide3_url = check_plain(theme_get_setting('slide3_url','nexus'));
  ?>

<div id="slidebox" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
  <li>
    <img src="<?php print base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'nexus') . '/images/slide-image-1.jpg'; ?>"/>
    <?php if($slide1_head || $slide1_desc) : ?>
      <div class="flex-caption">
        <h2><?php print $slide1_head; ?></h2><?php print $slide1_desc; ?>
        <a class="frmore" href="<?php print url($slide1_url); ?>"> <?php print t('CONTACT US'); ?> </a>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="<?php print base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'nexus') . '/images/slide-image-2.jpg'; ?>"/>
    <?php if($slide2_head || $slide2_desc) : ?>
      <div class="flex-caption">
        <h2><?php print $slide2_head; ?></h2><?php print $slide2_desc; ?>
        <a class="frmore" href="<?php print url($slide2_url); ?>"> <?php print t('CONTACT US'); ?> </a>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="<?php print base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'nexus') . '/images/slide-image-3.jpg'; ?>"/>
    <?php if($slide3_head || $slide3_desc) : ?>
      <div class="flex-caption">
        <h2><?php print $slide3_head; ?></h2><?php print $slide3_desc; ?>
        <a class="frmore" href="<?php print url($slide3_url); ?>"> <?php print t('CONTACT US'); ?> </a>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
</ul><!-- /slides -->
<div class="doverlay"></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there any solution for that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Drupal connector from Smartling that may be of help. Here is a [video](http://vimeo.com/95899855) showing how the connector works.

Many sites running on Smartling do language/country-specific image replacement, which is explained [here](http://support.smartling.com/hc/en-us/articles/200926458-How-to-Substitute-Image-Flash-or-Binary-Files).

Hope this helps,
Nataly

Comment: thnx a lot,I will check it

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT>
function english(){
$(#image).attr('src','http://link.to.your/english/image.png')
}
function greek(){
$(#image).attr('src','http://link.to.your/greek/image.png')
}
</SCRIPT>
<IMG id="image" src="http://link.to.your/greek/image.png">
<A HREF="#" onclick="english">Change to English</A><BR>
<A HREF="#" onclick="greek">Change to Greek</A>
```

Comment: it is better to create a dropdown and use change() function

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed it in page.tpl with php code. One if/else on your page language to set you picture path.
Regards, HashKey

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. 
To critique or request clarification from an author, 
leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, 
and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.